# What does the "minimumum-stability" key do when present in a package's composer.json?

Tags: composer-php

I frequently come across a `composer.json` for a specific package that has a `minimum-stability` key included. An example is reproduced below:

```json
{
  "name": "drupal/modulename",
  "type": "drupal-module",
  "description": "Example.",
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
}
```

I understand what this key does when it is present in the site's *root* `composer.json` (i.e. it will then disallow installation of packages with a lower stability than stipulated).

But what does `"minimum-stability": "dev"` do when it is present in a in a package's `composer.json`?

In the above example, there are no requirements. Will it do anything if there *are* other packages required?

I am only familiar with the Drupal ecosystem, where I've seen this a lot. I don't think this is significant, since using *composer* to manage dependencies is used a lot by other PHP frameworks as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does nothing when present in a non-root `composer.json`.

The [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) say:

> minimum-stability (root-only)

For packages, it would only have any effect if you were installing the package as as the root project (e.g. by using `git clone` and then  `composer install`, as opposed to installing it on an existing project with `composer require`).